# Why would Process.Start unexpectedly return false

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, process

While using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) to shell another executable (not a file type) why would it return false and fail to start the executable rather than throwing an exception? To be more clear, the documentation mentions the return to be "true if a process resource is started; false if no new process resource is started (for example, if an existing process is reused)." All explanations of "an existing process is reused" appear to be for launching files that open in an existing instance of the program that handles them (like starting a .jpg that opens in an existing image editor instance). The executable launched in this context is authored in-house and does nothing to prevent new instances from executing. No logging or other signs that the application even attempted to start are present. Feedback for why the process was not started is nowhere to be found.

It is worth noting that the issue becomes more reproducible the higher the number of executables launched in rapid succession. The same code in production environments does not appear to be failing, but the load is distributed better across many machines. In the test environment 100+ processes are started in rapid succession on a single machine and pretty consistently the last 7-10 are the only ones that fail to launch. The control process is able to detect the processes already running when it starts and will only start those not currently running. This appears to be working correctly, and when we do a full fresh start (all 100+ instances are verified to be stopped and then we start them) 7 or so fail to start but then we can restart the control process and the same executables with the same settings run successfully. It may be useful to know that all processes started are of the same executable with different command line arguments. The control process is a Windows Service, the spawned executables are command line applications with no dependency on the standard input or output streams.

In the process of troubleshooting this issue, to be safe, I have ensured the thread starting the external applications is running in a single-threaded apartment because ShellExecuteEx can depend on this, though I believe the framework now accounts for this. I have tried adding Thread.Sleep delays between process executions which do not appear to effect the quantity of applications that do not start (with varying delays attempted from 100ms to 300ms, and most recently an increasing delay after each instance going up to 1500ms or so).

Is there perhaps a maximum number of child processes imposed by windows, or perhaps some bug that happens when windows is trying to launch tons of processes at the same time? I have not been able to find a reasonable answer to *why* the execution fails. Here are the bits that launch the executable itself (some internals redacted, but all framework code intact):

```
        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(processPath)) 
        {
            processPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(
                Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                processPath));
        }

        ProcessStartInfo psi =
                new ProcessStartInfo(processPath, args);
        psi.UseShellExecute = true;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Trace("Starting {0} {1}", processPath, args);

        using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = psi;
            bool success = process.Start();
            if (!success)
            {
                // this is what doesn't make sense
            }
        }

        Trace("Started {0} {1}", processPath, args);
```

Comment: Is it not starting *any* process or some specific one?

Comment: @MiserableVariable - "In the test environment 100+ processes are started in rapid succession on a single machine and pretty consistently the last 7-10 are the only ones that fail to launch."

Comment: Sorry I didn't read that earlier. Does retry work?

Comment: Have you tried re-ordering the processes to ensure it is in fact the "order/number" of the processes rather than the processes themselves (or the process that was launched before it?)

Comment: Note that a return value of false does not indicate failure - only that a new process was not started.

Comment: Try running process monitor and/or P/Invoking ShellExecute or CreateProcess yourself just to eliminate some variables.

Comment: I've now reflected through the code. It seems ShellExecuteEx is either returning false with no error in GetLastError, or ShellExecuteEx is returning true but the ProcessId is 0. ProcMon does not show the application ever attempting to execute. Order is independent of the issue, it is simply the last several that fail.

Comment: Also, the applications function as sandboxes from one another and do not communicate with one another. None of them have special windows privileges to be blocking other processes, nor do any of them do anything directly with windows APIs anyway. They are designed as individual workers and until they receive units of work (which doesn't happen until after this) they all function the same (same executable, different work). Assuming these things to be true, order should be irrelevant.

Comment: ShellExecute has a lot of baggage; if you're just launching regular processes why not set UseShellExecute to false?

Comment: True, and I felt like there was a reason i t was being used, but this code didn't originate with me so that's worth experimenting with. That said, it doesn't change the fact that this is either undocumented behavior or I don't understand the docs. The question is still relevant to me. I'll report back on the CreateProcess version.

Comment: @Luke thanks for pointing out the (retrospectively) obvious; that did fix my issue, though I do still want to know how it is that the method can determine that the windows shell failed to launch it without some sort of error happening. Perhaps a shortcoming in ShellExecuteEx

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little surprised that it didn't throw Win32Exception.  Try retrieving the last Win32 error after Process.Start() fails.  You do that with:

```
var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

Then, assuming that you will get a Win32 error, look it up at this site:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx